# How to declare array type that can have int and floats

Tags: julia

I am a newbie to Julia and still trying to figure out everything.
I want to restrict input variable type to array that can contain int and floats.
I would really appreciate any help.

```
function foo(array::??)
```

Comment: Do you want Ints and Floats at the same time? That's not advised due to performance reasons. But if you want to, you can use Union{Int64,Float64} as the type. What are you trying to do?

Comment: As @ChrisRackauckas said, you generally do not want to mix floats and ints. But if you must mix floats and ints, you can declare the type as `array::Any` or `array::Number`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you don't want to mix them for performance reasons. However, if your array can be either Floats or Ints, but you don't know which it will be, then the best approach is to make it dispatch on the parametric type:

```
function foo{T<:Number,N}(array::Array{T,N})
```

This will make it compile a separate function for arrays of each number type (only when needed), and since the type will be known for the compiler, it will run an optimized version of the function whether you give it `foo([0.1,0.3,0.4])`, `foo([1 2 3])`, `foo([1//2 3//4])`, etc.

---

### Updated syntax in Julia 0.6+

```
function foo(array::Array{T,N}) where {T<:Number,N}
```

---

For more generality, you can use `Array{Union{Int64,Float64},N}` as a type. This will allow Floats and Ints, and you  can use its constructor like

```
arr = Array{Union{Int64,Float64},2}(4,4) # The 2 is the dimension, (4,4) is the size
```

and you can allow dispatching onto weird things like this as well by doing

```
function foo{T,N}(array::Array{T,N})
```

i.e. just remove the restriction on `T`. However, since the compiler cannot know in advance whether any element of the array is an Int or a Float, it cannot optimize it very well. So in general you should not do this...

---

But let me explain one way you can work with this and still get something with decent performance. It also works by multiple dispatch. Essentially, if you encase your inner loops with a function call which is a strictly typed dispatch, then when doing all of the hard calculations it can know exactly what type it is and optimize the code anyways. This is best explained by an example. Let's say we want to do:

```
function foo{T,N}(array::Array{T,N})
  for i in eachindex(array)
    val = array[i]
    # do algorithm X on val
  end
end
```

You can check using `@code_warntype` that `val` will not compile as an Int64 or Float64 because it won't know until runtime what type it will be for each `i`. If you check `@code_llvm` (or `@code_native` for the assembly) you see that there is a really long code that is generated in order to handle this. What we can instead do is define

```
function inner_foo{T<:Number}(val::T)
  # Do algorithm X on val
end
```

and then instead define foo as

```
function foo2{T,N}(array::Array{T,N})
  for i in eachindex(array)
    inner_foo(array[i])
  end
end
```

While this looks the same to you, it is very different to the compiler. Note that `inner_foo(array[i])` dispatches a specially-compiled function for whatever number type it sees, so in foo2 algorithm X is calculated efficiently, and the only non-efficient part is the wrapping above inner_foo (so if all your time is spent in inner_foo, you will get basically maximal performance).

This is why Julia is built around multiple-dispatch: it's a design which allows you to push things out to optimized functions whenever possible. Julia is fast because of it. Use it.

Comment: you explained it so well.

Comment: I thought `foo{T,N}(array::Array{T,N})` would also compile a separate version for each array element type (and thus be fast)... Why does that only happen when `T<:Number`?

Comment: It happens even if you don't specify `T<:Number`. The only reason why I did that in the first case is because that's really the approach you want to be taking in most cases. As I said, `function foo{T,N}(array::Array{T,N})` will compile just fine, but if you give it a `Array{Union{Int64,Float64},2}` then it won't optimize (still compile, but the resulting code is really ugly, check it out). Normally you'd want to have the type check to make sure you don't "mess up" like that.

Comment: Note that `Union{Int64,Float64}` is still a subtype of `Number`. The only distinction between `T` and `T <: Number` is that the latter will not allow non-number `eltype`s, which is appropriate sometimes but not always.

Answer (score 6):

This should be a comment to Chris' answer, but I don't have enough points to comment.

As Chris points out, using function barriers can be quite useful to generate optimal code. However be aware that dynamic dispatch has some overhead. This may or may not be important depending on the complexity of the inner function.

```
function foo1{T,N}(array::Array{T,N})
    s = 0.0
    for i in eachindex(array)
        val = array[i]
        s += val*val
    end
    s
end

function foo2{T,N}(array::Array{T,N})
    s = 0.0
    for i in eachindex(array)
        s += inner_foo(array[i])
    end
    s
end

function foo3{T,N}(array::Array{T,N})
    s = 0.0
    for i in eachindex(array)
        val = array[i]
        if isa(val, Float64)
            s += inner_foo(val::Float64)
        else
            s += inner_foo(val::Int64)
        end
    end
    s
end

function inner_foo{T<:Number}(val::T)
    val*val
end
```

For `A = Array{Union{Int64,Float64},N}`, `foo2` doesn't provide much speedup over `foo1` since  benefit of the optimised `inner_foo` is countered by the cost of dynamic dispatch.

`foo3` is much faster (~7 times) and could be used if possible types are limited and known ahead of time (as in above example where elements are either Int64 or Float64)

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/OBs0fmNmjCU for further discussion.