# julia: A few questions about generic types in functions

Tags: performance, types, julia

I'm adding types to some functions, namely for speed and clarity. I have a few questions about this. I'm asking them all here since I've seen other posts that do this. The questions are bolded for easier recognition.

There's a function that I'd like to add types to that counts the amount of negative values in a vector. I'd like to have it be compatible with Int and Float, just like an untyped function is. While convenient, Chris Rackauckas advises against it, see first comment of [How to declare array type that can have int and floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39380285) ,

> Do you want Ints and Floats at the same time? That's not advised due to performance reasons. But if you want to, you can use Union{Int64,Float64} as the type.

If a polymorphic function is necessary for some reason, then the better method appears to be to add types to the arguments by means of an `Union`. For this particular case, however, with `Number` and `Real` being supertypes of `Int64` and `Float64`, I thought these would be slightly faster than the untyped version.

This, however, doesn't seem to be the case, at least on my simple tests. I tested a function without argument types, another with `Any`, and two with types `Number` and `Real`, both supertypes of `Float64` and `Int64`.

```
notypes
median time:      1.006 ms (0.00% GC)
mean time:        1.152 ms (12.60% GC)

any
median time:      1.054 ms (0.00% GC)
mean time:        1.197 ms (12.05% GC)

union
median time:      1.062 ms (0.00% GC)
mean time:        1.210 ms (12.09% GC)

number
median time:      1.110 ms (0.00% GC)
mean time:        1.315 ms (14.18% GC)

real
median time:      1.015 ms (0.00% GC)
mean time:        1.168 ms (12.70% GC)

float
median time:      728.131 μs (0.00% GC)
mean time:        829.031 μs (11.53% GC)
```

Clearly, there is no significant improvement between the untyped function, and the ones typed as `Any` and `Number`. The `Real` function appears to have a very slight improvement, and the `Float64` function is the only with a noticeable improvement.

**Is a function typed for only `Int` and `Float` generally faster than one without types?** `Union{Int64,Float64}` is supertype of only two types, unlike `Number` and `Real` that span many more. This is why I thought the `Union` function would be faster than the rest (except the `Float` version). **Are `Union`s as slow as untyped in general?**

**Is there any performance improvement in typing a function with supertypes such as `Number` and `Float`, compared to leaving them untyped?**

**Is it the best julian practice to define a function for every possible argument type?** In this case, `Int64` and `Float64`.

For convenience's sake rather than performance's, **is there a shorter way to define Int-Float functions?** Perhaps, by defining a new type at the beginning? I tried doing this:

```
abstract type IF64 <: Union{Int64,Float64} end
```

but got an error

```
invalid subtyping in definition of IF64
```

Also, **what does the `N` mean in the function's definition?** (such as `where {T<:Union{Int64,Float64},N}` in `countMPvec_arrUnion`'s definition given below).

Lastly, **why does the `Float` function take less memory than the rest?** (`609.06 KiB` v. `921.56 KiB`) (This is the output of the benchmarks; code given below)

```
all other functions
  memory estimate:  921.56 KiB
  allocs estimate:  38979
float
  memory estimate:  609.06 KiB
  allocs estimate:  28979
```

Full code of the tests:

```
#= -------------------
   The different versions of the function
   -------------------
=#
function countMPvec_notypes(vec)
    nneg = 0
    lvec = length(vec)
    for i in 1:lvec
        if (vec[i] < 0)
            nneg += 1
        end
    end
    npos = lvec - nneg
    return (nneg,npos)
end

function countMPvec_any(vec :: Any)
    nneg = 0
    lvec = length(vec)
    for i in 1:lvec
        if (vec[i] < 0)
            nneg += 1
        end
    end
    npos = lvec - nneg
    return (nneg,npos)
end

# Works with Int and Float !!!
function countMPvec_arrUnion(vec :: Array{T,1}) where {T<:Union{Int64,Float64},N}
    nneg = 0
    lvec = length(vec)
    for i in 1:lvec
        if (vec[i] < 0)
            nneg += 1
        end
    end
    npos = lvec - nneg
    return (nneg,npos)
end

# Works with Int and Float !!!
function countMPvec_arrNumber(vec :: Array{T,1}) where {T<:Number,N}
    nneg = 0
    lvec = length(vec)
    for i in 1:lvec
        if (vec[i] < 0)
            nneg += 1
        end
    end
    npos = lvec - nneg
    return (nneg,npos)
end

# Works with Int and Float !!!
function countMPvec_arrReal(vec :: Array{T,1}) where {T<:Real,N}
    nneg = 0
    lvec = length(vec)
    for i in 1:lvec
        if (vec[i] < 0)
            nneg += 1
        end
    end
    npos = lvec - nneg
    return (nneg,npos)
end

function countMPvec_arrFloat(vec :: Array{Float64,1})
    nneg = 0
    lvec = length(vec)
    for i in 1:lvec
        if (vec[i] < 0)
            nneg += 1
        end
    end
    npos = lvec - nneg
    return (nneg,npos)
end

#= -------------------
   Functions for benchmark
   -------------------
=#
nums = [1.3; -2; 5]
nitertest = 10000

function test_notypes()
    for i in 1:nitertest
        countMPvec_notypes(nums)
    end
end
function test_any()
    for i in 1:nitertest
        countMPvec_any(nums)
    end
end
function test_arrUnion()
    for i in 1:nitertest
        countMPvec_arrUnion(nums)
    end
end
function test_arrNumber()
    for i in 1:nitertest
        countMPvec_arrNumber(nums)
    end
end
function test_arrReal()
    for i in 1:nitertest
        countMPvec_arrReal(nums)
    end
end
function test_arrFloat()
    for i in 1:nitertest
        countMPvec_arrFloat(nums)
    end
end
```

Then there's the benchmark cells. Each one of these should be run separately. Also, the full output from every cell is given at the end:

```
import BenchmarkTools
println("notypes")
@BenchmarkTools.benchmark test_notypes()

println("any")
@BenchmarkTools.benchmark test_any()

println("union")
@BenchmarkTools.benchmark test_arrUnion()

println("number")
@BenchmarkTools.benchmark test_arrNumber()

println("real")
@BenchmarkTools.benchmark test_arrReal()

println("float")
@BenchmarkTools.benchmark test_arrFloat()

#= -------------------
   Output of the benchmarks
   -------------------
=#

notypes
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  921.56 KiB
  allocs estimate:  38979
  --------------
  minimum time:     855.070 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      1.006 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        1.152 ms (12.60% GC)
  maximum time:     31.515 ms (91.59% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          4314
  evals/sample:     1

any
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  921.56 KiB
  allocs estimate:  38979
  --------------
  minimum time:     905.317 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      1.054 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        1.197 ms (12.05% GC)
  maximum time:     30.355 ms (96.33% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          4152
  evals/sample:     1

union
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  921.56 KiB
  allocs estimate:  38979
  --------------
  minimum time:     914.563 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      1.062 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        1.210 ms (12.09% GC)
  maximum time:     32.472 ms (90.09% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          4111
  evals/sample:     1

number
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  921.56 KiB
  allocs estimate:  38979
  --------------
  minimum time:     926.189 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      1.110 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        1.315 ms (14.18% GC)
  maximum time:     42.545 ms (97.21% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          3788
  evals/sample:     1

real
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  921.56 KiB
  allocs estimate:  38979
  --------------
  minimum time:     863.699 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      1.015 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        1.168 ms (12.70% GC)
  maximum time:     31.847 ms (96.50% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          4257
  evals/sample:     1

float
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  609.06 KiB
  allocs estimate:  28979
  --------------
  minimum time:     625.845 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      728.131 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        829.031 μs (11.53% GC)
  maximum time:     30.811 ms (97.38% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          5989
  evals/sample:     1
```

Comment: Besides the irrelevance of type annotations to performance, you should be aware that there are many pitfalls when benchmarking Julia code. It's good that you are using BenchmarkTools, but you are violating rule number one of Julia performance: avoid global variables. The vector `nums` is a global variable. Make sure to pass it as an input parameter to the benchmark code instead, and remember to interpolate with `$`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a single answer to all your performance-related questions: *type-annotation improves performance for structures but generally not for functions*. The post you read from Chris concerned the element type of an array (a structure), even though it appeared in terms of what types a function would accept. You should interpret it in that context.

In Julia you should type-annotate function arguments to control dispatch, not for performance. Why? Because the compiler will specialize each function for every concrete type you pass into it, in a sense automatically generating all those specializations you were thinking about writing out by hand. So the only reason to add a type annotation is to control which method gets called:

```
is_this_a_number(x::Number) = true
is_this_a_number(x) = false
```

Structures are a different story. You can read more about type-annotation in structures in the [Performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-abstract-container) section of the manual.

Finally, keep in mind that some things have changed since those early days of that question. In particular, [union splitting](https://julialang.org/blog/2018/08/union-splitting/) allows good performance in many circumstances with small `Union`s of concrete types (check each with `isconcretetype` if you're unsure).

> what does the N mean in the function's definition

The number of dimensions in the array.

Comment: Reading this and Chris' answer on the aforementioned post helped a lot. The topic is much deeper than I thought, so thanks for the links